# Add Database View in Entity Framework on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have a MVC project that i created models from my database. I am trying to add a new view from Visual Studio 2013  (update models from database clicking the add tab) but the view doesn't add to my project. The update wizards adds successfully new tables but not new views from db. Is there any other way to add my view?

Comment: are you selecting Your Views in "Add" Tab while updating ?

Comment: Yes I am selecting the views. When I add tables it works fine, the problem is for the views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved when i checked from sql management studio to include an id field in select statement from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Although the resource is quite an old one, it should help anyways:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi This same problem i handled three days back.There is a problem in your visual studio. Please install visual studio update in your system.The resources are in the online.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307 Visit this page and download and install it surely  will work

Thanks